# An equality of support of monomials.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R=k[x,y,z]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $k$. Let $m,v$ be monomials in $R$ of degree $d$. Let $I$ be a monomial ideal (i.e. ideal generated by monomials) in $R$ and $m\in I+(v)$ but $m\notin I$. Let $\mathrm{supp}(m)=\{i 
: x_i\text{ divides } m\}$ and $\mathrm{supp}(v)=\{i : x_i\text{ divides } v\}$.

**Q) Is it true that $\mathrm{supp}(m)=\mathrm{supp}(v)$?**

Comment: I think it is. You might try to argue with two cases by contradiction. Case 1: there exists $i\in supp(m)$, such that it is not in $supp(v)$; case 2: there exists $i\in supp(v)$, such that it is not in $supp(m)$. In both cases, you can show that the $v$ has to be canceled, so it is a contradiction with the assumption $m\not\in I$.

Comment: The answer to your question is trivially yes: $m\in I+(v)$ but $m\notin I\implies v\mid m$ and since $\deg m=\deg v$ they differ by a non-zero constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is easier than it looks for the following reason: if $m \in I + (v)$, but $m \not \in I$, $m$ must have the form $v^l n$, where $l \in \mathbb N$ and $n \not \in I$. Then $m=v^l n$. But $m$ and $v$ have the same degree $d$, hence $n$ must be a scalar and $l=1$.

So $m=cn$, and so their support is clearly equal.

Comment: Does it imply that if $m=r x^{a} y^{b} z^c$ where $r$ is a scalar then $n= x^{a} y^{b}z^c$?